# Is this PHP login function safe?

Tags: php, authentication

I am currently re-writing my functions script (PHP) for my login system. Is the below code safe and a "good" way to check if the user is logged in?

```
    function loggedin()
    {
        $ID = ($_SESSION['ID']);
        $sql = "SELECT `online` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = '$ID'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
        if ( $count== 1)
        {
            if ($_SESSION['ID'] && $_SESSION['session_id'])

            {
                if ( $row['online']== 1)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: no, it is not (hello, sql injections)

Comment: What happens if "$row['online']" is not 1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Beware Bobby Tables!

```
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['ID']);
```

Escape any and all input parameters with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Or better yet, use parameterized queries with (MySQL)[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Oh yes thanks I forgot about that. about PDO I dont really know how to use it, I will look into it in the future I really just want to get a safe working login system. Thanks

Comment: @Elliott, NP. PDO might have a bit of a learning curve (not as bad as you might think) but after you get over that hurdle I think the readability benefit alone justifies its use.

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely worth adding

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

to prevent [session fixation](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation.).

So this

```
if ( $row['online']== 1)
    return 1;
```

becomes this:

```
if ( $row['online']== 1)
{
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, make sure you check if the session exists first.

```
function loggedin()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['ID'])) return 0;
    $ID = ($_SESSION['ID']);
    ..
```